# what gets returned in this Python code for Quicksort?

Tags: python, return

I am a beginner and am trying to understand what exactly gets returned by the "return" in the second line and why the code runs fine whether or not I add a return statement at the beginning of the first line below:

```
        quickSort(arr, start, pivot_index-1)
        return quickSort (arr, pivot_index+1, end)
```

Following is the actual code:

```
def quickSort(arr, start, end):
  
    if start >= end:
        return arr  
    else:
        pivot_index = partition(arr, start, end)
        quickSort(arr, start, pivot_index-1)
        return quickSort (arr, pivot_index+1, end)

def partition(arr, low, high):
    pivot_value = arr[high]
    for i in range(low,high):
        if arr[i] < pivot_value:
            arr[i], arr[low] = arr[low], arr[i]
            low += 1
    arr[low], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[low]
    pivot_position = low
    return pivot_position
#--------------------------------------       
arr = [1,2,9,10,6,15,8,24,3,1,8,13,6,2,7]
print(quickSort(arr,0,len(arr)-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `quickSort` function here uses a recursion, so in your line of question it returns the return value of its call with arguments `(arr, pivot_index+1, end)`. Since you need to sort both parts of an array, on the left `(quickSort(arr, start, pivot_index-1))` and on the right of pivot (return `quickSort (arr, pivot_index+1, end))` to get the correct result, adding the return statement in front of the line `quickSort(arr, start, pivot_index-1)` will result in not sorting the part on the right of pivot, and getting incorrect output (even the code does not crash).
If you want to learn more about quickSort, here is the resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/
If you want to learn more about recursion, you can reference this link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-recursion-data-structure-and-algorithm-tutorials/
Clarification regarding the comment:
In general, when writing recursive functions, it is important to understand what value do you expect your function to return and how you plan to use it later, how exactly it will be passed through the call stack, and whether you modify the argument(s) in the process. For example, with the `quickSort` function, we could even omit the last `return` statement in the last line because the function modifies the original argument `arr`, and the expected output will be anyway stored in this variable, even if the function will return `None`. If we run the following code:

```
def quickSort(arr, start, end):
  
    if start >= end:
        return arr  
    else:
        pivot_index = partition(arr, start, end)
        quickSort(arr, start, pivot_index-1)
        quickSort (arr, pivot_index+1, end)

def partition(arr, low, high):
    pivot_value = arr[high]
    for i in range(low,high):
        if arr[i] < pivot_value:
            arr[i], arr[low] = arr[low], arr[i]
            low += 1
    arr[low], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[low]
    pivot_position = low
    return pivot_position
  
arr = [1,2,9,10,6,15,8,24,3,1,8,13,6,2,7]
quickSort(arr,0,len(arr)-1)
print(arr)
```

the `arr` variable will be the same as the return value in the first version of the code. Another factor worth taking into account when deciding if a function like `quickSort` should return something is how you plan to use its return value later in your code. However, it is not always the case that the recursive function will modify the original argument. For example, the recursive `factorial` function is not supposed to modify the number it is called with, it is supposed to return the numeric value instead. Consider he following code:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

In this case, it is actually important that the `factorial` function returns `n * factorial(n-1)` value, because the next function call in the stack depends on it and the function does not modify the initial `n` value.
So, in general, when deciding what a return value in the recursive step for a recursive function should be, it is important to understand whether the function modifies the initial argument passed to it, how it will be used later in the code, and how exactly the recursion depends on this return value.

Answer to the comment about `return arr` statement:
The `return arr` statement in the base case returns the array passed as an argument in that particular quickSort call in case it is already sorted (no changes need to be made further). It is different from the `return` in the recursive step because it includes no recursion. In general, recursive functions divide the problem until they reach the base case, which can be dealt with without the use of recursion (in this case, having an already sorted array). When learning how to design a recursive function, it is often useful to think about the base case first (it is usually easier than the recursive case), and make sure that each recursive step takes you closer to the base case. It is often helpful to draw trees, especially if you are still learning, since they help to visualize how the function works and what it should return.

Comment: Thanks so much. I should have asked my question differently. While I can see, given the code is already written, what is happening, I am trying to understand how to think using this example. Is there any way you can explain how you would decide, if you are writing this program, let me call quick sort once, but let me know ask it to return anything, then make another call, but this time ask it to return whatever. Hope I am not asking for too much to fit in such a short space here.

Comment: @ArNY I've edited my initial response to answer your question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. It is really helpful. I see what the "return" before the second call to quicksort () does. But just one more question. I know why return in the base condition is important but what is  arr in "return arr" statement in the base case doing and how does that differ from the return in the last call to quicksort? How do you think through these while writing the program? Do you advise that I always start with drawing the tree and see what has to return to what?

Comment: @ArNY I edited my answer again.

Comment: Thanks again. Your replies are very useful. I hope I remember all this.